# What sort of provisioning profile should I use for Hudson building my iOS app?

Tags: ios, hudson, xcodebuild, provisioning-profile

I'm building an iPhone app and I am tasked with automating the build to integrate with our Hudson-based build of our back-end Java components.  I see Apple docs mentioning 'build bots,' but I haven't seen what Apple recommends for creating an automated build/CI system for iOS apps.

And I'm not sure I understand the differences among development and distribution and ad-hoc profiles, so I hope experienced members won't mind helping me figure out which type to request and install.

My Hudson is slaving a build Macintosh using a non-privileged user account.

I would like to take successful builds and enable my co-workers and other interested parties to install them on their own iDevices.

What's the right type of profile to use for xcodebuild to sign the app and make it installable?

Thanks in advance!

Andrew Wolfe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use an AdHoc profile if you're wanting to distribute the app to people who aren't using xcode. remember that you'll have to add the device UDIDs of each person you want to be able to run the app to the profile.

in your project (in xcode), create a separate AdHoc target so you can specify the profile. then when you set things up on hudson, you specify the AdHoc target on the build command line.

i highly recommend looking at https://testflightapp.com/. it's a great service and a god send when you're dealing with sending out adhoc builds to people. and it's free!

Comment: Mike, that makes a lot of sense.  Thank you!